# How to make a function receive multidimentional array of arbitrary size in C++?

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, arguments

I was trying to make a function which takes a matrix as input and outputs some function of it in C++. But I want it to work on arbitrary size mxn matrix. i.e. I cannot specify in the arguments of the function the values of n (double matrix[][n]) . Because n will be arbitrary.
Is there any way I can pass on an arbitrary mxn 2 dimensional array to a function?
Thanking you in advance.
-indiajoe

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/index.html

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for the boost Library links..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template <typename T, size_t W, size_t H>
void foo(T (&array)[W][H]) {
   // Do stuff with array here
}
```

Comment: How about dynamic matrix allocation ?

Comment: @Eric: Why? It's not needed. The OP wanted a way to pass around a two-dimensional array with arbitrary dimensions, and here it is!

Comment: If the code of the function is large, it can cause huge increase of the application code size if called with lots of different size of matrix. Not every compiler is smart enough to merge template function.

Comment: @Sylvain: It was not specified in the question that the code should be optimised for executable size. Perhaps it should be optimised for legibility, maintainability and ease of use, in which case this is the solution. (Did you like my clever avoidance? :P)

Comment: @Sylvain - yes, this code causes a lot of superfluous specializations.  Better to use the iterator approach if you need to use template code.  It would still be specialized on column count, but at least not on row count too.  Iterator approach also has the benefit of being more legible.

Comment: @Crazy: Define "iterator approach" please. Standard iterators are all templates. And the above looks very legible to me.

Comment: @Tomalak : Thanks a lot, This method worked perfectly. @Sylvain 's suggestion to collapse 2d matrix into a 1d array of pointers, also worked for my special case of 2d matrix case. But if I have to generalize to higher dimensions, I think I will have to use this template method. Right? 
Thanks a lot...

Comment: @indiajoe: Collapsing a 2D matrix into a 1D array of pointers is a solid approach, and I'd probably recommend it for higher than three dimensions, and certainly if you were using dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to do it. The best way is probably to define a matrix class and to pass a const reference to an instance.

```
class matrix
{
    double* values;
    size_t m;
    size_t n;
public:
    matrix(size_t m_, size_t n_)
    : m(m_), n_(n)
    {
        values = new double[m * n];
    }

    ~matrix()
    {
        delete[] values;
    }

    double& operator(size_t i, size_t j)
    {
        assert(i < m);
        assert(j < n);
        return values[i + m * j];
    }

    const double& operator(size_t i, size_t j) const
    {
        assert(i < m);
        assert(j < n);
        return values[i + m * j];
    }
private:
    matrix(const matrix&);
    matrix& operator =(const matrix&);
};

void function(const matrix& matrix);
```

If you don't want to use a class, and your data is stored linearly (as in my matrix class), you can simply pass a pointer to a double, and the dimensions:

```
void function(double* values, size_t m, size_t n);
```

If you really want to use double[m][n] and have a function accepting any matrix size, you can convert it manually to a double**, by doing something like that:

```
void function(double** lines, size_t m, size_t n);

void client()
{
    const size_t m = ...;
    const size_t n = ...;
    double matrix[m][n];

    double* temporary[m];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++ i) {
        temporary[i] = &matrix[i][0];
    }

    function(temporary, m, n);
}
```

Or, using a template function to do the conversion:

```
void function(double** array, size_t m, size_t n);

template < size_t M, size_t N >
void function(double array[M][N]) {
    double* temporary[M];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++ i) {
        temporary[i] = &array[i][0];
    }
    function(temporary, M, N);
}
```

This is because an array can only decay once to a pointer (that is double[n] decay to double* but double[m][n] decay to double*[n]).

Comment: Your second suggestion to collapse 2d matrix into a 1d array of pointers, seems to be the simplest solution for my problem. Thanks a lot to everyone for all the various ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

using the Standard C++ Library, you could do that:

```
typedef std::vector<double> Dim;
typedef std::vector<Dim> Matrix;

void workOnMatrix(Matrix& matrix)
{

}
```

EDIT: I remove the reference to **STL** since SGI's **STL** and the **Standard C++ Library** are not the same things. So much different it seems that they must not be taken one for another.

Comment: *resists urge to go on "STL" rant*

Comment: I dislike C-style coding, so going STL is no problem for me ;)

Comment: This is a much better solution than Tomalak's.

Comment: I imagine the rant was about confusing the C++ Standard Library and the STL -- STL was a pre-standard library that was partially incorporated into the C++ Standard Library; they're not the same thing (despite all-too-common usage).

Comment: @Stuart - I should hope not...rants should be reserved for issues that actually matter.

Comment: @Crazy, @Stephane: I agree: standard containers *all the way*. But, that's not what this question is about. Blame the OP!

Comment: @Crazy: It *does* matter; you just evidently don't have any exposure to language newcomers whom this matter confuses hugely. Think outside of your bubble please.

Comment: @Tomalak - "Think outside your bubble please." <- That's a might bit rude.  Just because I disagree with you doesn't mean I'm in a bubble.  Newcomers are not confused by applying the term STL to the parts of the standard library that have that historical root.

Comment: @Crazy: They are. I work with them daily and see it all the time. Worse, I see in CVs people misusing the term to mean all of the library, other parts of the library, etc. Just because you are apparently lucky enough not to encounter these people does not mean that they are not highly prevalent in some areas, hence my remark. I remain amazed that so many people don't care about these groups, or have somehow managed to avoid them. I don't really want to start this here, though, hence my original *resistance*. :)

Comment: @Tomalak - Using the term the way everyone else does isn't confusion.  There is nothing other than the pedantic point that parts of the standard library originally came from the STL vs. ARE the STL is being confused.  Unless the team is actually using the real STL the point is completely moot and can be quite safely ignored.  I could probably count the amount of such teams with my fingers (a bit of an overstatement maybe, point is...hardly anyone is doing so).  There is no actual effect this misuse has on peoples' understanding of code.

Comment: @Tomalak - BTW, comments like your original here are not resisting the urge.  Not commenting at all is.

Comment: @Crazy: It's not using the term the way everyone else is. As I said, people use it to mean all of the library, other parts of the library, etc. There is no consistency. Once more you ignored my point which is that the problem goes further than whether your own team is using the real STL: it creates a global ambiguity which affects language newcomers and, potentially, people in other development teams. This ambiguity is enforced each time you use the wrong term.

Comment: @Tomalak, sorry I had never known that SGI STL was so different from the Standard C++ Library. I intimately believed they were almost the same. As I have not used SGI's STL for a long time, I will stick to the **Standard C++ Library** term. I'm gonna edit to remove the term STL.

Comment: @Stephane: Case in point :) In fact I do leave the "STL" tag on posts because it has far more posts than "stdlib", and because I'm at least aware that -- to my pain -- most people will still use this term. So for a post tag, it still possibly makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it Tomalak's way, but I certainly wouldn't recommend it.  You could never call that function from within another that wasn't also a template if the array was passed through params.  This means almost your entire program would have to be templated code.  OK, in theory, but generally impractical.

You can't use the `double**` interface as you've found out.  You could cast to that type but then you also need the size information to be passed in so that you can:

```
my_ptrptr[row * col_size][col];
```

You have to be explicit about the dimensions like this because the compiler no longer knows what it needs to.

The best answer to your problem is to not do it that way.  Leverage the STL so that you don't have to deal with hokey crap like this.  Use Stephane's answer.

Yet another thing you can do though, if you're going to use templates anyway, is to write it to be generic:

```
template < typename Iter >
void fun(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  // begin[x][y]... (*begin)[y]...++begin, etc...
}
...
double arr[arr_row_count][arr_col_count];
fun(arr, arr+arr_row_count);
```

This one has the major benefit of working with ANYTHING that looks like an array of arrays.  This means it would make an excellent 'interim' method that you can use with your `double[][]` types until such time as you can begin using something better like the `std::vector` and/or `boost::array`.  Do it Tomalak's way and you won't be able to make this change later...yet another reason not to use that method.

Comment: "You could never call that function from within another that wasn't also a template if the array was passed through params." Well, that's complete nonsense. What on earth makes you think that? Are you actually talking about arrays whose dimensions are only known at runtime? Because my answer was, of course, about normal statically-allocated arrays, and my function can be used from any context in code.