# How to have a function input of arbitrary size in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I found an answer for C++: [How to make a function receive multidimentional array of arbitrary size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157274/how-to-make-a-function-receive-multidimentional-array-of-arbitrary-size-in-c)

But I'm having trouble translating it to VB.NET.

I could collapse the different dimensions to just a vector array... But out of curiosity, is there a way to have a function take an arbitrary size double in VB.NET?

Below is some code so that you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim x(), x1(,), x2(,,) as Double

manipulate_in_matlab(x)

manipulate_in_matlab(x1)

manipulate_in_matlab(x2)

function manipulate_in_matlab(ByVal x as ???)
'This function calls in another program (Matlab in this case)

     Dim x_size as Integer = x.Rank

     'I'm not sure how to proceed here, right now the 'dumb' way would be a case statement. But what I need to do is create an array of equal size. For the 3-dimension case:

     Dim r, c, d As Double
     r = x.GetUpperBound(0)
     c = x.GetUpperBound(1)
     d = x.GetUpperBound(2)

     Dim x_imag(r,c,d) as Double


end function
```

Comment: What have you tried? By default, in .Net, passing in an array as parameter is of arbitrary size. Unless I am misunderstanding what you are asking, which is entirely likely as you've provided no details.

Comment: @anothershrubery thanks for taking a look, I've added some edits

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, you're trying to pass in a multidimentional array and then break it apart and use it within the function?  If so, you might want to take a look at this: http://net-informations.com/vbprj/programflow/multi-dimensional-array.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling code:

```
Dim a(5) As Double
Dim a1(5, 5) As Double
Dim a2(5, 5, 5) As Double
test(a, a1, a2)
```

Function Definition

```
Private Sub test(ByVal a() As Double, ByVal a1(,) As Double, ByVal a2(,,) As Double)

End Sub
```

OR use overloading if you know there are only certain combinations

```
Dim a(5) As Double
Dim a1(5, 5) As Double
Dim a2(5, 5, 5) As Double

test(a)
test(a1)
test(a2)


 Private Sub test(ByVal a() As Double)

    End Sub

    Private Sub test(ByVal a(,) As Double)

    End Sub

    Private Sub test(ByVal a(,,) As Double)

    End Sub
```

Edit 3: sorry I keep thinking of different things

Calling code:

```
test1(a)
test1(a1)
test1(a2)
```

Function def:

```
Private Sub test1(ByVal a As Array)
    Debug.WriteLine(a.Rank)

End Sub
```